# Catching C# errors at the class library level

Tags: c#, logging, exception, class-library

I am trying to work out an error logging solution for an enterprise-level class library.  Some of the requirements:

- It will be used by multiple end-point applications (hence why it should be handled in the classlibs)
- It should sink its data into a SQL Server database for easy storage.  This also goes into the third one:
- It should be able to support a custom web application reading its data.

There's one more requirement, which is a 'very nice to have'.  That is, it's not critical, but if it's not feasibly possible I'd better have a darned good reason for it.

- It should not require specialized Logger objects in its end-point applications.  They should be able to simply throw exceptions and the logging software should handle things from there.  Having a specific USING command is kosher, though.

The first three points are not that difficult, all things considered.  A quick logging class and some stored procedures, call it a day at noon, right?  The last point is something I don't know how to approach, though.  I've seen it done before in a friend's code, so I know it is possible, but said friend has unfortunately passed on and his code is lost to the ether.  Is there anyone out there who could point me in the correct direction of having a class library object somehow catch all errors coming up from an end-point application to process them?

Comment: Re: #2: so how are you going to log the error of inability to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: So you want to know how to make your class library catch all errors it might throw?

Comment: Are you saying you want all unhandled exceptions in the application to be handled by your library?

Comment: Aspect programming could be useful for logging purposes.

Comment: @Seva: Probably throw off a panic email to the sysadmin on duty.  That is out of the scope of the question, though.

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, that's basically the idea here.  There should be some class library level error handling to report any errors instead of simply having the application go belly-up, or whatever have you.

Answer (score 4):

If you're wanting to catch all unhandled exceptions not originating within your own call stack, you could look into utilizing the [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) object:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) => {
    // Your logging logic
};

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s, e) => {
    // Your logging logic
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Microsoft Enterprise Library could be of use here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649552.aspx

Comment: Unless I've missed something, it's absolutely not.  The main thrust of the final requirement is that logging should simply be something that snaps in, you should not have to refactor basic throwing logic to work with it.  The enterprise library requires a moderate amount of refactoring and thus isn't appropriate.  There are other reasons why we've discarded the idea but the short nature of these comments doesn't allow me to get into them here.

Comment: The enterprise library has some good logging and exception handling although I do admit it is a bit over the top for some cases. It really depends what you want to log, there is a good example of logging unhandled exceptions for and asp.net project here...

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/15/2802.aspx

Not sure if that is of too much use to you without knowing more about your setup. Another good exception logging system is elmah which I have used before and also logs to xml or sql...

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

but again that is asp.net. Could you give us any more info?

Comment: ELMAH is not appropriate because it is at the application level, and I need this to be at the class library level, where everything is collected and handled in a uniform manner - if that makes sense.  Honestly, with that being the case, I think it is safe to dismiss almost anything that is specifically for an 'asp.net project', simply because that's inevitably going to be handling the end application instead of on a higher level where the logging may be included and accessed from a class library.

Answer (score 1):

When I read enterprise level class library I have these requirement in my head:

- **Your component shall not throw exceptions and disturb the system.**
- **It shall deal with errors gracefully and be able to recover from errors.**

Such requirements are a good read for you as a developer before you go to bed. All error scenarios even the ones in your wildest dreams will become reality sooner or later and you wake up at 3 am in the night screaming.

The requirements sound good but its implications are far reaching. If you try to catch all errors in your component you do nothing else than error hiding. Such systems tend to be slow and sometimes they do simply stop working and nobody knows why because some follow up error did bring the system into a state where really nothing does work. The sad thing is that if you attach a debugger to that stale machine you will not see the original error that caused the problem but a follow up problem from where you have to work backwards to the original problem. If you want to log to SQL server I can assure you that you will end up with no or missing logs quite frequently.

You should consider more reliable log destinations (custom event log, log file, ... or both). And avoid async logging at all costs since an unhandled exception will bring down the process much faster than you are able to log it away in your logging thread.

In reality you need to bring the system to a halt as early as possible when a fatal error has occured. The errors from which you can safely recover without corrupting state are usually very few but they are worth the effort since you need to design your class library to be robust (deal with expected errors) and safe (throw exceptions, log them, ...).

During the design phase it is easier to think of a perfect system that can cope with all errors. Software architects like such systems. And they can get away with it because on paper it looks good. Or to put it in other words: Bubbles don´t crash.

But at execution time your class library is using

- Real Physical Memory (OutOfMemoryException)
- Real Hard Disc space (at least log files) (Hard disc full)
- Real CPU cycles (100% CPU)
- Real Stack Space (StackOverFlowException)

If you try to hide fatal errors the system has only become harder to debug but it will still fail since your library will is consuming shared resources which do not exclusively belong to your component. It is better to stop working immediately in such situations than to continue and let others fail as well.

The idea to hide all errors inside a component is flawed since you cannot prevent fatal errors inside your component to influence other components in the system.

That beeing said I hope you did not ask how to catch all errors at class library level but at your end-point applications where you display errors to the user and log them (hopefully only once and not again in every layer because you do not trust the other layers). As others have pointed out you can get your hands on unhandled exceptions which did terminate a thread which will in turn terminate your process when your error handler is left. Besides this it is a good idea to put a try/catch block around your Main method to catch errors in the main thread. If you application has an UI (Windows Forms) you should also register to the Application.ThreadException event which will be called when an exception propagates out of a Window message handler.

Yours,
  Alois Kraus

Comment: I am not sure where you got the idea that I am attempting to hide errors.  Quite the contrary, I am attempting to give them more visibility and persistence.  I do not intend to swallow or hide fatal errors; if the program is to crash, then it shall crash.  I will simply know how it got to that point.  Your point about more reliable destinations is well taken, though.  We were actually going to add in an MSMQ event sink after we got the simpler case of the SQL sink working.

Comment: Sorry if I did misinterpret your question. MSMQ is reliable but quite slow. If yout want to know how you got to that point you need to add tracing to your application as well. Logging is mainly meant for error reporting but not to follow your application flow since the amount of data you would need to log is several magnitudes higher. http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2009/06/21/132968.aspx. Errors should be transported as reliable as possible whereas tracing should be as fast as possible.